# Java streams: Add to map but avoid mutation

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, grouping, java-stream

I often find myself in a situation where I need to create a `Map` of objects from a Set or `List`.
The key is usually some String or Enum or the like, and the value is some new object with data lumped together.
The usual way of doing this, for my part, is by first creating the `Map<String, SomeKeyValueObject>` and then iterating over the Set or List I get in and mutate my newly created map.

Like the following example:

```
class Example {
   Map<String, GroupedDataObject> groupData(final List<SomeData> list){
      final Map<String, GroupedDataObject> map = new HashMap<>();
      for(final SomeData data : list){
         final String key = data.valueToGroupBy();
         map.put(key, GroupedDataObject.of(map.get(key), data.displayName(), data.data()));
      }
      return map;
   }

}

class SomeData {
   private final String valueToGroupBy;
   private final Object data;
   private final String displayName;

   public SomeData(final String valueToGroupBy, final String displayName, final Object data) {
      this.valueToGroupBy = valueToGroupBy;
      this.data = data;
      this.displayName = displayName;
   }

   public String valueToGroupBy() {
      return valueToGroupBy;
   }

   public Object data() {
      return data;
   }

   public String displayName() {
      return displayName;
   }
}

class GroupedDataObject{

   private final String key;
   private final List<Object> datas;

   private GroupedDataObject(final String key, final List<Object> list) {
      this.key = key;
      this.datas = list;
   }

   public static GroupedDataObject of(final GroupedDataObject groupedDataObject, final String key, final Object data) {
      final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
      if(groupedDataObject != null){
         list.addAll(groupedDataObject.datas());
      }
      list.add(data);
      return new GroupedDataObject(key, list);
   }

   public String key() {
      return key;
   }

   public List<Object> datas() {
      return datas;
   }
}
```

This feels very unclean. We create a map, and then mutate it over and over.

I've taken a liking to java 8s use of `Stream`s and creating non-mutating data structures (or rather, you don't see the mutation). So is there a way to turn this grouping of data into something that uses a declarative approach rather than the imperative way?

I tried to implement the suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453814/3478016 but I seem to be stumbling. Using the approach in the answer (the suggestion of using `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.mapping`) I'm able to get the data sorted into a map. But I can't group the "datas" into one and the same object.

Is there some way to do it in a declarative way, or am I stuck with the imperative?

Comment: Is it you only want the *last* `data.displayName()` and `data.data()` for each `data.valueToGroupBy()`?

Comment: @Bohemian the `data.displayName()` is the same for each `data.valueToGroupBy()`. In my current problem, the `valueToGroupBy` is in English, and the `displayName` is in Swedish. But they are the same.

Comment: That does't answer my question. Yes or no: Are you trying to put only the last data seen for each key in the output map?

Comment: @Bohemian Ah. Misread, I think. I want *all* `data.data()` that have the same `valueToGroupBy` in the same `GroupedDataObject`. Basically turning my `List<SomeObject>` into a `Map<String, Tuple<String, List<Object>>>`.  Does this answer your question or am I still misunderstanding you?

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere. So for a given key, `displayName` is constant and you need to concatenate all `data` lists into a single list, under each key, correct?

Comment: @Bohemian Correct.

Comment: So what you really want is a `Map<String, ObjectWithDisplayNameAndDataList>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` with a merge function instead of `Collectors.groupingBy`.

```
Map<String, GroupedDataObject> map =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(SomeData::valueToGroupBy,
                                  d -> {
                                     List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
                                     l.add(d.data());
                                     return new GroupedDataObject(d.valueToGroupBy(), l);
                                  },
                                  (g1,g2) -> {
                                      g1.datas().addAll(g2.datas());
                                      return g1;
                                  }));
```

The `GroupedDataObject` constructor must be made accessible in order for this to work.

Comment: I don't think this will compile.

Comment: This perfectly solved my problem. Though longer in lines, breaking out the lambdas makes this so much more reusable. I also found that the constructor does not have to be accessible. You can use static factory methods just as well.

Comment: @Eran not as it was. But with a little rewriting of it it works. One `of` to take in a `String` and an `Object`, to use in the value-lambda, and one `of` that take a `String` and two `Set<Object>` to use in the merge-lambda.

Comment: @Chewtoy I wouldn't create a new `GroupedDataObject` instance in the merge lambda. It would be more efficient to add to one of the existing instances the data from the other instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you avoid the `GroupedDataObject` and simply want a map with a key and a list you can use `Collectors.groupingBy` that you have been looking into.

Collectors.groupingBy will allow you to do this:

```
List<SomeObject> list = getSomeList();

Map<SomeKey, List<SomeObject>> = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeObject::getKeyMethod));
```

This will require SomeKey to have proper implementations of `equals` and `hashValue`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes streams are not the way to go. I believe this is one of those times.

A little refactoring using `merge()` gives you:

```
Map<String, MyTuple> groupData(final List<SomeData> list) {
    Map<String, MyTuple> map = new HashMap<>();
    list.forEach(d -> map.merge(d.valueToGroupBy(), new MyTuple(data.displayName(), data.data()), 
      (a, b) -> {a.addAll(b.getDatas()); return a;});
```

Assuming a reasonable class to hold your stuff:

```
class MyTuple {
    String displayName;
    List<Object> datas = new ArrayList<>();
    // getters plus constructor that takes 1 data and adds it to list
}
```